# Combine: dataTaskPublisher(for:) doesn't output value

Tags: swiftui, combine

I try to separate network layer code with Combine, create a class `HTTPAsyncManager` to hold network request. But I found the output is not triggered from `dataTaskPublisher(for: url)`.

And I think the problem is on this line `private var requests = Set<AnyCancellable>()`, if I move it and network code into contentView and create a State `@State private var requests = Set<AnyCancellable>()` for Cancellable. It could output the data. But I do want to separate it from ContentView. What should I change?

```
import Combine
import SwiftUI


class HTTPAsyncManager {
    private var requests = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    func fetch(_ url: URL) {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
            .handleEvents(receiveSubscription: { print("Receive subscription: \($0)") },
                              receiveOutput: { print("Receive output: \($0)") },
                              receiveCompletion: { print("Receive completion: \($0)") },
                              receiveCancel: { print("Receive cancel") },
                              receiveRequest: { print("Receive request: \($0)") })
            .map(\.data)
            .decode(type: User.self, decoder: decoder)
            .replaceError(with: User.default)
            .sink(receiveValue: { print($0.name) })
            .store(in: &requests)
    }
}
```

```
import Combine
import SwiftUI

struct User: Decodable {
    var id: UUID
    var name: String

    static let `default` = User(id: UUID(), name: "Anonymous")
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Fetch user") {
                let url = URL(string: "https://www.hackingwithswift.com/samples/user-24601.json")!
                HTTPAsyncManager().fetch(url)
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

#### Console output

```
Receive subscription: DataTaskPublisher
Receive request: unlimited
Receive cancel
```

Comment: The problem here is that you are not holding any reference to your `HTTPAsyncManager `. So it gets deallocated immediately. You should have something like `private let httpManager = HTTPAsyncManager()` in your view. And then call `httpManager.fetch(url)`.

Comment: Oh, never think that could be a problem. Could you explain more about why `HTTPAsyncManager()` would gets deallocated immediately. I think it creates an instance and exist in ContentView.

Comment: Check the answers below. `ContentView` only keeps a reference to the manager if you create a reference to it as an instance property. Otherwise the `ContentView` has no reference to the manager. And the manager gets deallocated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are not holding any reference to your `HTTPAsyncManager` in your view. So it gets deallocated immediately. Your view should look like:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    private let httpAsyncManager = HTTPAsyncManager()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Fetch user") {
                let url = URL(string: "https://www.hackingwithswift.com/samples/user-24601.json")!
                httpAsyncManager.fetch(url)
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue occurs because you create an instance of `HTTPAsyncManager` and throw it away immediately which cancels the subscription.

You need a strong reference for example with

```
private let manager = HTTPAsyncManager()
```

and in the button write

```
manager.fetch(url)
```

---

A modern alternative is an `actor` which retains itself until the task has finished

```
actor HTTPAsyncManager {
    
    func fetch(_ url: URL) async {
        do {
            let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
            let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(User.self, from: data)
            print(result.name)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
Button("Fetch user") {
    Task {
        let url = URL(string: "https://www.hackingwithswift.com/samples/user-24601.json")!
        let manager = HTTPAsyncManager()
        await manager.fetch(url)
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh actor, good to know. Thanks, vadian.

Comment: Hi @vadian, just curious if async and await can totally replace combine or which one is preferred.

Comment: In my opinion async/await cannot totally replace Combine. Simply spoken the "core competence" is defined by their names.  Async/await is for performing all kind of asynchronous and concurrent tasks and Combine is for *combining* and manipulating different kinds of publishers into one stream. For example the `removeDuplicates` and `scan` operators are unique in Combine.